# gVim memory overload/ application crash while reading large files

Tags: database, vim, vi

I need to read a fairly large (~5 Gb) file on gVim. It is delimited by a newline char. every 150 characters or so. However, when I try to open them, the editor tries to load it for a minute and crashes.
A quick look at at my memory usage indicates that it uses 90% of my 8 Gb memory before running out. Some users on S.O have pointed out Vim's use of preprocessor directives and suggested disabling them. I tried to do that but it still wont load.
You can view the discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/527093/gvim-crashing-while-opening-8gb-text-file). Any other tips?
Cheers - Suhas

Comment: There's the LargeFile vim plugin wich disables as much as possible but in the end, gVim is probably not your best option to open 5Gb files *(I doubt any editor is)*. What do you hope to do with it once it's opened? Most likely, other tools are better suited for the job.

Comment: If you only need to *read* that file, why don't you use a pager like `less` or `more`?

Comment: Well, I actually need to parse some strings out of these files. Currently, I wrote a C++ program to read the file line by line and write it into 10 files. I have close to 50 such files and the sheer logistics of it scares me. And about the LargeFile plugin, it doesn't do the trick. I've implemented a similar vimrc file which removes most preprocessor directives.

Comment: Why not change your C++ program to do the parsing instead? Then there's no need to split the file. Or use something like `sed` or `awk` instead.

Comment: I ended up using C++ to parse. I was reluctant at first because my splitting took a long time ~4 hours. Using some optimization ( reducing I/O calls , Reading 112 MBs at a time) I was able to get it down to 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an interactive editor, Vim has to load the entire file into memory. Plugins like the mentioned [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) can help with the performance of Vim (by turning off syntax highlighting, swapfile, etc.), but cannot relieve the memory pressure.

If you really need to edit such huge files, I only see two options:

- `split` (a Unix tool, also supplied by Cygwin for Windows) the file into smaller chunks, edit those (interactively, with Vim), and then re-join via `cat`
- use `sed` (whose command syntax is similar to Vim's Ex commands, as both derive from `ed`) or a real programming language (like Perl, Python, etc. that can read from input streams) to modify the file non-interactively; these programs don't need to keep the entire file in memory and therefore can work very efficiently